# How to connect two listview?

Tags: asp.net

I am doing a project in asp.net, in that i have a listview in one page(**Home.aspx**) that takes the GroupID & GroupName from the **productgrp** table in database. And i have the other page named **product.aspx**,in that i have an another listview which have to take the values like GroupID,ProductID,Image,Description from the **productmst** table by comparing GroupID from the **productgrp** table. What i have to do is,if i click on the GroupName in the listview in Home.aspx, it have to go to product page and display that another listview as i mentioned before. what i have to do for this? Help me....

Thanks in advance
**Hari**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understood your question, you need to carry some information from the one ASP.NET page to another one.

There are several options to do it:

1. You can use your Session object and persist some information there:

   `Session["somestring"] = somedata;`
2. You can pass some parameters, like GroupID etc. to the new page either by GET (termed "query strings" in ASP.NET) or POST, here is an example how to do it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw.aspx
3. You can register your own routes for ASP.NET application and then dynamically generate the page link to pass your data in a RESTful way. Here is some info about it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx

Comment: Alaudo thanks for ur reply. I want to carry the database information from onepage to another,when the user clicks on anyone of the list of GroupNames in homepage(i gave hyperlink to each of the GroupName taken from the database and shown it as a vertical sidebar list)How can i do it using session object? Help me i dont know how to do it..

Comment: Can you provide me with some more code of you webpage? Then I could directly elaborate on this code the action you'd like to have.